# Multipart POST and objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, post, multipart

I'm trying to upload an image to a server, and having difficulty wrapping my head around the concept of a multipart request, if it is possible to have some sort of explanation, that would be great.

The other issue I'm having is creating one in objective-c. I'm trying to upload a UIImage, and I've got the data all encoded to base 64 like I've seen in other parts, but how do I generate the request itself?

Also, I would like to avoid using 3rd party libraries, so I can understand what is going on more, instead of "oh, it's magic that this library does for me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [`setHTTPBody:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setHTTPBody:) on an `NSMutableURLRequest` for the content you want to  upload. Obviously that content will need to comply with [RFC 2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388).

All of this can be done by hand, but third party libraries make it easier, and will handle more edge-case scenarios than your own code, unless you want to put a lot of effort into re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Convert UIImage into base64 using [NSData_Base64](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip) link where integrating it in your project.

Now use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for multipart POST